# How to run local host .net app connecting with Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, localhost, azure-sql-database, connection-string, azure-sql-server

I use the connection string that Azure provides but it doesnt work. Perhaps connection string of Azure app service and local host is different? Or is there anything I should fix besides my connection string for the app able to run in local host?

Answer (score 0):

Connection string should be the same from whereever you are connecting from. Things to try:

1. Check that your connection string is valid / access is by connecting to it from SQL Server Management Studio in your local machine
2. If you are copying the connection string from Azure SQL Portal, you will need to explicitly replace {password} with the actual password.
3. If connecting string is all correct but you still cannot connect, check your firewall rules in Azure SQL

Comment: I can connect through SSMS and I’ve replaced my own password in the connection string. If the application is using model/db first and I’m migrating the mssql to Azure sql is there anything else I should modify?